# Python Return multiple Variables from a function

Tags: function, python-3.x, return

Not so much of a question as a valuable observation for people using python.
Unlike the majority of other programming languages, you can return multiple variable from a function
without dealing with objects, lists etc.

simply put

```
return ReturnValue1, ReturnValue2, ReturnValue3
```

to return however many you wish.

and to retrieve them:
`ReturnValue1, ReturnValue2, ReturnValue3 = functionName(parameters)`

But remember to do it in order just like assigning a parameter for a function.

Cheers

Comment: This is not a proper question in the Stack Overflow definition; and the observation has been made in numerous other posts on the site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we may accept posts that have interesting observations like yours, they still have to be in question and answer format. You might put "how do I return multiple variables from a function?" in your post, and put "simply put `return ReturnValue1, ReturnValue2, ReturnValue3` to return however many you wish" in an answer that replies to the post. (although, as Martijn observes, even a properly formatted post may be closed if it's a duplicate of existing content)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

As I am not able to just comment on your "Question", I have to put this into an answer:

To be precise, the return-value will be a tuple. So technically you are not returning multiple values, but an instance of the class `tuple`, containing those exact values. This provides the opportunity to receive those values in quite a lot of different ways:

```
def f():
    return 1, 2, 3

one, two, three = f()   # one = 1, two = 2, three = 3
all_three_values = f()  # all_three_values = (1, 2, 3)
a, *b = f()             # a = 1, b = [2, 3]
assert isinstance(all_three_values, tuple)   # True
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
lst = ['a','s','d','f','w','e']
def list2variables(lst):
    di = {} 
    for i in range(len(lst)): # capture index to form dict
        di[lst[i]]=lst[i]
    for k, v in di.items(): # move elements as global variable
        globals()[k] = v

    return globals() # return so that can be used in future
```

little change can be done in function to take dict as argument too